# C: How do I properly free the memory when lineptr == NULL in getline

Tags: c, file

From the man page: https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline

```
ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
```

> If *lineptr is NULL, then getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line, which **should be freed by the user program**. (In this case, the value in *n is ignored.)

Since is a school project **I CAN NOT USE MALLOC** by teacher instructions, I don't care about the contents of the line (I just want to skip it easily). How can I free the memory? in which buffer it is allocated?

Note: Since it is a more theoretical question I do not add any code

Comment: Does your man page have example code at the bottom?  Or did you consider providing a pre-allocated buffer?

Comment: @StephenNewell I'm using https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline as reference

Comment: "How can I free the memory?" --> `free(ptr)`.  `malloc()` not needed.

Comment: And that page has an example, including freeing the memory.

Comment: In the manual page you linked to there's an example showing its use, and how to free the memory. That, together with the full description, should help understanding how it works. Can you please [edit] your question to elaborate and be more clear about your thoughts, and what is unclear to you?

Comment: Did you get an explicit permission to use `getline`? If not you might be in for a surprise.

Comment: You realize that `getline` uses `malloc` (which is why you need to `free` the memory), right?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) as well as [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) Then [edit] your question to improve it. For example, what is your actual assignment? Please copy-paste it (as text!) in full and complete into the question.

Comment: I was sleepy and thinked in using the function as `getline(null, &n, stdin)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example usage:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t line_size = 0;
    
    while (1) {
        ssize_t line_char_count = getline(&line, &line_size, stdin);
        
        if (line_char_count == -1) break;
        
        // Use your line string, e.g. printing it:
        printf("Echo: %s", line);
    }
    
    free(line); 
}
```

What you'll notice is that the string `line` is `NULL` to start. As the documentation explains, the first invocation of `getline` will make it allocate a buffer for you (as if it called `malloc` internally). Subsequent calls to `getline` in the loop will reuse the same buffer.

Once you send end-of-input with ctrl-d, the loop will exit, and `free` will be called to free the line.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't care about the contents of the line (I just want to skip it easily).

Instead of `getline()`, code could use a simply loop.  No allocation worries.

```
int ch;
while ((ch = fgetc(stream)) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
  ;
}
```